# For loop creating dynamic strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong in the code below?

```
ZeroList = ["53", "52", "24", "26", "36", "37", "40", "41", "43", "44", "45"]

for ZeroID in ZeroList:
    if row[ZeroID]:
        R+str(ZeroID) = float(row[ZeroID])
    else:
        R+ZeroID = 0
```

#### Doing the following output:

```
print R53
print R52
print R24
```

Would output:

```
2392.118329
232.298323
142.521513
```

I've tried several options to try and create the dynamic string, in the above example there are two ways that I've tried.

Any ideas?

#### EDIT

```
        ZeroList = {"R53": "", "R52": "", "R24": "", "R26": "", "R36": "", "R37": "", "R40": "", "R41": "", "R43": "", "R44": "", "R45": ""}

        for ZeroID in ZeroList:
            if row[int(ZeroID[-2:])]:
                ZeroList[ZeroID] = float(row[int(ZeroID[-2:])])
            else:
                ZeroList[RZeroID] = 0

        datatoapp = [row[0], row[1], row[8], row[9], '{0:0.2f}'.format(float(ZeroList[R52]))]
```

Comment: What is `R` and what is your desired output?

Comment: Are you trying to create dynamic *variables*? If so, don't. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: `R+str(ZeroID) = float(row[ZeroID])` this part is wrong. there shouldn't be sentence left to equal sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your data *out* of your variable names.

Use a dictionary to store your items, creating dynamic keys instead:

```
results = {}

for ZeroID in ZeroList:
    if row[ZeroID]:
        results[R+str(ZeroID)] = float(row[ZeroID])
    else:
        results[R+str(ZeroID)] = 0
```

Comment: how am I supposed to call my data later on?

See my edit for my edits

Comment: Why not just refer to the row indices *directly*? `row[ZeroID] = float(row[Zeroid])`, then `print row[53]` later on.

Comment: @Hyflex: Then *test* for that; test the length of the row.